# how to hide and show named divs according to enum value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, enums

I'm trying to hide and show divs based on a enum from a . I know this should be rather simple, but I'm very rusty on my JavaScript (and jQuery).

My select form is:

```
<div id="recurrency">
    <form:select path="recurrency">
        <form:option value="-" label="--Please Select"/>
        <form:options items="${recurrency}"/>
    </form:select>
</div>
```

Where And I also have a bunch of divs declared as:

```
<div id="dayInterval">
    // something
</div>
```

Same for `weekInterval` and `monthInterval`.

My piece of JavaScript code is:

```
$().ready(function () {
            $('#recurrency').on('change', function () {
```

`alert(recurrency);

            if (recurrency.value == 'DAILY') {
                $('weekInterval').hide();
                document.getElementById('weekInterval').style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById('monthInterval').style.display = 'block';
            }
            if (recurrency.value == 'WEEKLY') {
                document.getElementById('dayInterval').style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById('monthInterval').style.display = 'block';
            }
            if (recurrency.value == 'MONTHLY') {
                document.getElementById('dayInterval').style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById('weekInterval').style.display = 'block';
            }
        });
    });`

The alert part on the JavaScript code always returns `Object HTMLCollection`. I'm sure this is quite simple, but I can't see the way out here.

Can someone throw me a hand? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the change event handler for the `select` element. Then inside the change event handler, you can get the value of the select and then set the display of the target elements by using [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

In your case `recurrency` refers to the `div` element(since that is the ID of the div) that is why you are getting that alert message like that.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#recurrency select').on('change', function() {
    var value = this.value;
    $('#dayInterval').toggle(value == 'DAILY');
    $('#weekInterval').toggle(value == 'WEEKLY');
    $('#monthInterval').toggle(value == 'MONTHLY');
  }).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="recurrency">
  <select path="recurrency">
    <option value="-" label="--Please Select" />
    <option value="DAILY">DAILY</option>
    <option value="WEEKLY">WEEKLY</option>
    <option value="MONTHLY">MONTHLY</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="dayInterval">DAILY</div>
<div id="weekInterval">WEEKLY</div>
<div id="monthInterval">MONTHLY</div>
```

Comment: nice! Works like a charm! Thanks!