# how to hide and show named divs according to radio value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This one is quite similar to my other question on:

[how to hide and show named divs according to enum value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35714135/how-to-hide-and-show-named-divs-according-to-enum-value)

Idea here is slightly different, though. The toggle() jQuery function is related to a radio button which is coded below:

```
<div id="recurrent">
    <label for="recurrent">Recurrent? </label> 
    <input type="radio" id="idtrue" name="recurrent" value="true">Yes 
    <input type="radio" id="idfalse" name="recurrent" value="false" checked>No
</div>
```

The div to toggle is:

```
<div id="ifRecurrentTrue">
    /// something
</div>
```

And the adapted jQuery from the other question is:

```
$('#recurrent select').on('change', function () {
    var value = this.value;
    $('#ifRecurrentTrue').toggle(value == true);
}).change();
```

I bet it's just a matter of different functions, right?

Again, thanks in advance!

Comment: Did't see the element with `select` tag

Comment: Actually, there shouldn't be one. Just the radio buttons controlling what's to show. It was a typo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the `input` elemetns by its name, so use the attribute equals selector instead of the element selector `select`

```js
$('#recurrent input[name="recurrent"]').on('change', function() {
  $('#ifRecurrentTrue').toggle(this.checked && this.id == 'idtrue');
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="recurrent">
  <label for="recurrent">Recurrent?</label>
  <input type="radio" id="idtrue" name="recurrent" value="true">Yes
  <input type="radio" id="idfalse" name="recurrent" value="false" checked>No
</div>

<div id="ifRecurrentTrue">
  /// something
</div>
```

Comment: Arun, you're the man! Just a little something I forgot to add to the question. On page load the `<div id='recurrent'> ... </div>` should start toggled off.

Comment: that should work bases on which radio is selected, isn;t it? that should work now

Comment: before `$('#recurrent input[name="recurrent"]').on('change', function() {` I added `$('#ifRecurrentTrue').toggle();` initializing the div toggled off. I know this isn't very ellegant, but it's working now. Thanks again!

Comment: or you can just say `<div id="ifRecurrentTrue" style="display: none">`

Comment: @gtludwig `$('#ifRecurrentTrue').toggle();` won't be the right method, if you prefer js to do this then use `$('#ifRecurrentTrue').hide();`

Answer (score 0):

Did't see the element with `select` tag on provided code, could be `input`. Replace `select` with `input` like following:

```
$('#recurrent input').on('change', function () {
  var value = this.value;
  $('#ifRecurrentTrue').toggle(value == true);
}).change();
```

Comment: Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {  
      $('input:radio[name=recurrent]').on('change', function () {
        var values = this.value;
        $('#ifRecurrentTrue').toggle(values =='true');        
    }).change();
      
    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="recurrent">
        <label for="recurrent">Recurrent? </label> 
        <input type="radio" id="idtrue" name="recurrent" value="true">Yes 
        <input type="radio" id="idfalse" name="recurrent" value="false" checked>No
    </div>
    <div id="ifRecurrentTrue">
        /// something
    </div>
```